# Change of Variables in an Ordinary Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we have an ordinary differential equation
$$\tag{1} \frac{d^2 f}{dx^2}+a(x)\frac{d f}{dx}+b(x)f(x)=c(x)$$
It could potentially be useful to transform this differential equation into
$$\tag{2} g(u)\frac{d^2 f}{du^2}+a(x(u))\frac{du}{dx}\frac{d f}{du}+b(x)f(x(u))=c(x(u))$$
for some known function $g(u)$.

Is there a general procedure for finding an invertible change of variable $u(x)$ such that we can transform equation 1 to equation 2?

Comment: Do you have a specific case in mind or is it just a general question ?

Comment: Since equation is linear in f, maybe you can use the laplace transform (depending on how easy it is to find the inverses)?

Comment: This was a general question.  I did not have a specific example in mind.